# Register Handler Module in IIS with Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I have problem with IIS and web.config. I deploy a website by copying it on a new computer.
The website I copy contains the web.config, and the dll I want to register as a Handler Mapping. So my web.config already looks like :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="MyHandler" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\Scripts\MyHandler.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="bitness64" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It's visible and listed when I click on the Handler Mappings in IIS.
But after the copy and rebooting of IIS, it's not taken into account.
For it to be taken into account, I need to manually edit the mapping on IIS, then click Ok. At that point, I have prompt confirming that it will be taken into account.

The problem is, I want to deploy this site with a Powershell script. It seems a simple copy + IIS reboot is not enough.

What should I do for this handler mapping be taken into account with Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I continued researching and find my own answer. I need to add it in the CGI and Retriction List using Powershell:

```
Add-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/security/isapiCgiRestriction" -Value @{path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\Scripts\MyHandler.dll" ; allowed="true"}
```

and then it works.